# calling a function which may exist within a package

Tags: perl, package

I have a script that will parse a list of packages. The actual list of packages is not known till run time.
*Some* of these packages have a couple subroutine. The name of the subroutine is fixed (preBuild and postBuild). I am having trouble invoking these sub-routines.
Below code illustrates my attempts.
Question is: How to call a function which may exist, while ignoring it when it doesn't.

```
foreach my $p (@pkgList) {
  $funcName="$p::preBuild";
  ## 1. doesn't work. Never defined
  if (defined (&$funcName)) {
   &$funcName
  }
  ## 2. Cops out first time it hits a packet without the subroutine
  if (ref (&$funcName) eq "CODE") {
   &$funcName
  }
  ## 3. same as 2.
  eval $funcName
}
```

Comment: `"$p::preBuild"` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: I find the 'require' in Test::More, and Perls 'can' work will for this.

Comment: ikegami: Thanks for pointing that out. I actually later did $p."::preBuild". Plus the 'can' trick worked. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Perl provides the [`UNIVERSAL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/UNIVERSAL) base class for all packages, and `UNIVERSAL` provides the `can(subname)` method. With this you can test for the availability of arbitrary functions in arbitrary packages.

```
sub Foo::foo { 42 }
sub Baz::foo { 19 }
foreach $pkg (qw(Foo Bar Baz Quux)) {
    if ($pkg->can('foo')) {
        print "foo in $pkg: ", $pkg->foo(), "\n";
    } else {
        print "foo in $pkg: not found\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
foo in Foo: 42
foo in Bar: not found
foo in Baz: 19
foo in Quux: not found
```